# can't find info.plist in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, plist

So the regular intro: I am a newbie to objective c, searched everywhere and could not find, so please help...

All I want to do is to set my app to get location updates in the background - THAT'S IT. I know that I suppose to add location to UIBackgroundModes in the info.plist file in my project, however I have just NO CLUE where info.plist is.

All I see under my project Build Settings under Packaging is info.plist file (with Release and Debug underneath). No presence of UIBackgroundModes whatsoever.

Any help would be greatly welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Search for *AppName*-Info.plist where *AppName* is the name of your app.

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome! Slightly different cause I have Xcode 4, but worked perfectly!

Answer (score 17):

1. Hit Cmd-1 to make sure you're on the project navigator tab in the left pane.
2. Then click the main project table entry (the top one with your project name).
3. Click the "Info" tab in the main area (not the "Build Settings")

You're now looking at your Info.plist fields. You can right-click and Add Row under Custom iOS Target Properties.

The actual .plist file also exists in your project called `ProjectName-Info.plist`, probably in the `Resources` folder of your project.